# How do access modifiers help in get;set;?

Tags: c#

I need a in-depth answer to this question. How are these three int different from each other?

```
class whatever{
private int a {get; set;}
private int b {public get; private set;}
private int c {private get; public set;}
}
```

I would really appreciate it if I am provided with some code to experiment it in VS Community.
And do tell me that by not providing access providers at all, what happens? (As in the case of int a)

Comment: Why don't ask google for it first? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx#Anchor_2 is the first result it gives you

Comment: Only the first compiles, the other 2 do not. Anyway, the documentation is a good place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx

Comment: I disagree? The other two would compile except that you cannot set int b outside of the class and get in c outside of the class? Or am I mistaken here

Comment: @bi0phaz3 They do not compile. You can only put an access modifier on one of them; either the `get` or the `set`. Not both.

Comment: Ah, I learn something new everyday, thanks!

Comment: @AshishJacob - if you are not specifying any access modifiers then by default all fields and properties will be Private

Comment: @Dennis_E  Okay. That really didn't compile. Thanks. But that happened because the access modifiers for {get; set;} should be less 'public' than the one used for the int (in this case private). My real question is how using access modifiers in get; set; affect the int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 1.0, you could only put one access modifier on the entire property.
(There also weren't auto-implemented properties yet)

```
private int status;
public int Status {
    get { return status; }
    set { status = value; }
}
```

means that both the getter and setter are public, because the property is public.

In C# 2.0, they thought it might be helpful to have different modifiers for the getter and the setter, so they made it so that you can 'override' one of the accessors. There are certain rules, for instance the overridden one has to be more restrictive than the modifier of the property itself.
The following example means the getter is `public` (because the property has the `public` modifier) and the setter is `private`, because it has been overridden.

```
private int status;
public int Status {
    get { return status; }
    private set { status = value; }
}
```

So you can say `Status = 2;` from within the class, but you can no longer call it from outside the class.

Why didn't they make it like the following?

```
private int status;
int Status {
    public get { return status; }
    private set { status = value; }
}
```

Because that would break backward compatibility. The C# 1.0 example will still have to compile in the new version. When you introduce new features to a language, you have to make choices. This is the one they made.

And of course, in C# 3.0, we got auto-implemented properties, which made our lives a lot easier:

```
public int Status { get; private set; }
```

However, this is not truly a readonly property. For that, we had to wait for C# 6.0:

```
public int Status { get; } = 5;
```